# Get the tooltip text contained showing the argument list of a sub or function using Application.MacroOptions

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel VBA: Is it possibile to get the text contained in the tooltip which shows the argument list of a sub or function?

The `Application.MacroOptions` method knows the argument "ArgumentDescriptions" but it is possibly only set. Is there any way to read this info?

[image]

Comment: Maybe the `Object Browser` would help? Press `F2`

Comment: I need this info in VBA code for a function/sub created in other module or class.

Comment: The Application.MacroOptions Method has argument "ArgumentDescriptions" but It Is possibile only set. Is there any way to read this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Get the tooltip text contained showing the argument list of a sub or function ... The `Application.MacroOptions` Method has (the) argument `ArgumentDescriptions` but it Is possibile(!) only set. Is there any way to read this info?"*

► Afaik there is no built-in way.

**Possible workaround**

As you *"need this info in VBA code for a function/sub created in other module or class."*,
you might want to analyze your code modules by referencing the
`"Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3"` library in the VB Editor's menu.
[image: Library reference needed]

*Caveats*:

- Security: Requires to trust access to the VBA project object model.
- Rights: If not only for your personal use, consider that other corporate users may
  not have enough rights to turn that feature on.
- Self reflection: Mirrors the currently compiled/saved code only, so it might not reflect the latest code when the searched procedure body line has been changed.
- Line breaks: The following approach assumes that the entire procedure info is coded in one line -
  *not regarding closing line breaks via* `"_"`;
  it should be easy to extend the [`.Lines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/visual-basic-add-in-model/properties-visual-basic-add-in-model#lines) result in these cases by your own (e.g. benefitting from the count argument or by additional loops through the next lines).
- The following code doesn't intend neither to cover or to optimize *all* possibilities,
  but to direct you to a solution keeping it short & simple.

**Function `GetSyntax()`**

```
Function GetSyntax(wb As Workbook, Optional ByVal srchProcName As String = "GetCookie") As String
'Purp: Show name & arguments of a given procedure
'1) escape a locked project
    If wb.VBProject.Protection = vbext_pp_locked Then Exit Function ' escape locked projects
'2) loop through all modules
    Dim component As VBIDE.VBComponent
    For Each component In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
        ' Debug.Print "***"; component.Name, component.Type
        Dim found As Boolean
        '3) loop through procedures (as well as Let/Set/Get properties)
        Dim pk As Long              ' proc kind enumeration
        For pk = vbext_pk_Proc To vbext_pk_Get
            'a) get the essential body line of the search procedure
            Dim lin As String
            lin = getLine(component.CodeModule, srchProcName, pk)
            'b) found non-empty code line?
            found = Len(lin) <> 0
            If found And pk = 0 Then GetArgs = lin: Exit For
            'c) get proc info(s) - in case of Let/Set/Get properties
            Dim Delim As String
            GetSyntax = GetSyntax & IIf(found, Delim & lin, "")
            Delim = vbNewLine       ' don't change line order
        Next pk
        'If found Then Exit For     ' if unique proc names only
    Next component
End Function
```

**Help function `getLine()`**

```
Function getLine(module As VBIDE.CodeModule, ByVal srchProcName As String, ByVal pk As Long) As String
'a) define procedure kind
    Dim ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind
    ProcKind = pk
'b) get effective row number of proc/prop body line
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim effectiveRow As Long
    effectiveRow = module.ProcBodyLine(srchProcName, ProcKind) ' find effective row of search procedure
'c) provide for non-findings or return function result (Case 0)           
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 0                                       ' Found
        Dim lin As String
        'Syntax: obj.Lines (startline, count) As String
        lin = Trim(module.Lines(effectiveRow, 1))
        getLine = lin
    Case 35                                      ' Not found
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
    Case Else
        Debug.Print "** " & "   Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description: Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
    End Select
End Function
```

**Possible Test call**

```
    Dim procList, proc
    procList = Split("getCookie,foo,myNewFunction", ",")
    For Each proc In procList
        MsgBox GetSyntax(ThisWorkbook, proc), vbInformation, proc
    Next
```